# Need a better solution to a hackerrank challenge

Tags: c++

So I am new to competitive programming and I have been trying to solve this challenge for the past hour or so. I'm pretty sure my solution is overly complicated so can someone give me a better solution please? My code is pretty bad so if you can pls provide me with some feedback.

***The challenge***

You are given the day of the week for the first day of a month (M) (e.g. 1-Monday, 2-Tuesday, 3- Wednesday ...) and a date (D). You need to find the day of the week for the date given.

Constraints:
1<=M<=7
1<=D<=31

e.g.
Input: 1 30
Output: 2

My (bad) code:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int find_answer_for_more_than_7_days(int start,int day){
    cout<<day%7 + start - 1;
    return 0;
}
int find_answer_for_less_than_7_days(int start,int day){
    if ((start + day - 1)>7)
        cout<<start+day - 8;
    else
        cout<< start + day  - 1;
    return 0;
}
int find_answer(int start, int day){
    if (day>7)
        find_answer_for_more_than_7_days(start, day);
    else if (day<7)
         find_answer_for_less_than_7_days(start,day);   
    return 0;
}


int main() {
    int m,d;
    cin>>m>>d;
    if (d!=1){
        if (d%7 == 0){
            if (m != 1)
                cout<<m-1;
            else
                cout<<7;
        }
        else{
            if (m == 1){
                    if (d>7)
                        cout<<d%7;
                    else if (d<7)
                        cout<< d;
                }
            else if (m == 7){
                if (d > 7)
                    cout<<d - 7*(d/7) - 1;
                else if (d< 7)
                    cout<< d - 1;
            }
            else{
                find_answer(m,d);
            }
            }
        }
    else
        cout<< m;
    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Try posting this here instead, for a more receptive audience: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: *I am new to competitive programming and I have been trying to solve this challenge for the past hour or so.*  Seems to me that using outside resources for **competitive programming** is like cheating at solitaire or using a solver for sudoku.  Why bother at all?

Comment: @Eljay what do you mean?

Comment: I mean:  why bother doing the challenges at hackerrank at all?  Since they are an entertainment for you to solve those challenges with your best solution, but you've abdicated solving it by asking other to solve it for you with a better solution.

Comment: Well I'm trying to improve so I want to look at other people's solutions and receive feedback

Comment: My understanding of plain English is that a "date" consists of a month, day, and year, and not a single value between 1-31. The question is unclear.

Comment: @Konos not gonna tell you how to do you, but imo the best way to improve is to gain a solid understanding of the fundamentals of computer programming. If all you do is copy better code without understanding the principles, all you have really learned how to do is cut and paste answers off stackoverflow and hope they work or tweak them until they seem to.

Comment: @Taekahn Thank you, I am not going to be doing that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a start it would help if the code would actually be correct:

```
int find_answer_for_more_than_7_days(int start,int day){
    cout<<day%7 + start - 1;
    return 0;
}
```

`start = 7` and `day = 6` produces 12.

All those special cases in main are unlikely and costing you far more time then simply doing the general math. Just do

```
cout << ((m + d - 2) % 7) + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Maths does the work.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int day_of_the_week(int M, int D){

    return (D % 7 + M - 1) % 7;
}

int main(){
    cout << day_of_the_week(1, 30);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The C++20 answer:

```
std::chrono::weekday
find_answer(std::chrono::weekday first, std::chrono::day day)
{
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    return first + (day - 1d);
}
```

Just add the number of `days` beyond the 1<sup>*st*</sup> to the `weekday`.

`find_answer(Monday, 30d)` returns `Tuesday`.